# php html debugging issues

Tags: php, html

This is my php html code, I'm trying to make a web calculator.

Down in the php section where I check for errors I'm facing two issues:

1 - The message "please fill in all the REQUIRED fields !" keeps showing up even after correcting the error after refreshing

[image: this ing the screenshot]

2 - In the part where I check when selection division if the second number is equal to 0, the message doesn't show

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="revision.php" method="post">
        <label for="">Number 1 : </label>
        <input type="number" name="num1" placeholder="first number" >
        <br><br>
        <select name="operator" id="operator" >
            <option value="add">+</option>
            <option value="minus">-</option>
            <option value="multiply">*</option>
            <option value="divide">/</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <label for="">Number 2 : </label>
        <input type="number" name="num2" placeholder="second number" >
        <br><br>
        <button>calculate</button>
        <br><br>
    </form>

    <?php 
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

            //grabing variables
            $number_1=$_POST["num1"];            
            $number_2=$_POST["num2"];   
            $operator=$_POST["operator"];       
            
            //checking for errors
            $errors=false;
            if(empty($number_1) || empty($number_2) || empty($operator)){
                echo "please fill in all the REQUIRED fields !";
                $errors=true;
            }
            if($operator==="divide" && $number_2===0){
                echo "you can't divide a number by ZERO !!";
                $errors=true;
            }
            if(!is_numeric($number_1)||!is_numeric($number_2)){
                echo "you can't enter but numbers !!";
                $errors=true;
            };
            if(!$errors){
                $result=0;
                switch($operator){
                    case "add" :
                        $result=$number_1+$number_2;
                        break;
                    case "minus" :
                        $result=$number_1-$number_2;
                        break;
                    case "multiply" :
                        $result=$number_1*$number_2;
                        break;
                    case "divide" :
                        $result=$number_1/$number_2;
                        break;
                    default :
                        echo "something i don't know about went wrong !!<br>";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run your code, I do not encounter your first problem if I fill out the two boxes. Your second problem is because you are comparing the numeric `0` with a string version of `'0'` using strict equality `===`. You could use just `==` or you could possibly convert the text to a number

Comment: For the first issue string `'0'` is empty.

Comment: for the first issu : the problem is that when i run the code and don't put a number in one of the cases it shows the message : that s good but when i do it next time correctly the message doesnt go away , i don't know why